# Creating array from class values typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some class like this

```
export interface ILanguage {
  shortName: string;
  fullName: string;
}
export class Languages {
  static readonly FRENCH: ILanguage = { shortName: 'fr', fullName: 'FRENCH' };
  static readonly DUTCH: ILanguage = { shortName: 'nl', fullName: 'DUTCH' };
}
```

I need to create simple array from this this class that will look like this

```
const array = [{ shortName: 'fr', fullName: 'FRENCH' }, { shortName: 'nl', fullName: 'DUTCH' }];
```

I know I can start with

```
Object.keys(Languages).forEach
```

And that push to array, but I didnt sure about syntax

Comment: What's the purpose of using a class with static values here? I'd almost certainly just create a POJO (POTO?) with liberal `as const` to get the readonly semantics: `const languages = { FRENCH : { shortName: 'fr', fullName: 'FRENCH' } as const, DUTCH : { shortName: 'nl', fullName: 'DUTCH' } as const} as const`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there, you could use `Object.values`

```js
class Languages {
  static FRENCH = { shortName: 'fr', fullName: 'FRENCH' };
  static DUTCH = { shortName: 'nl', fullName: 'DUTCH' };
}
console.log(Object.values(Languages))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `toArray` function in your `Languages` class:

```
static toArray() {
  return Object.values(this);
}
```

or make it a getter:

```
static get asArray {
  return Object.values(this);
}
```

This way you have a simple and reusable way to access your languages as an array, without having to always do `Object.values(Languages)`.

As a site note, you can also make your `Languages` class `abstract` since it seems you'll only have `static` members, but this is optional.